# ajax success function receive information from php

Tags: php, ajax, callback

I'm not able to receive data from php script with ajax. I have an form sending the information to the php script. This is just a test. If it works I want to receive information from a database.

```
    $('.search-member-submit-btn').click(function () {
    var firstname = $("#search-member-firstname").val();
    var lastname = $("#search-member-lasttname").val();

    $.ajax({//AJAX request
        type: "POST",
        url: "/website/include/process/send_membersearchrequest_process.php",
        async: true,
        data: {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $(".search-member-result-address").html(data);
        },
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="search-member-result-container">
          <address class="search-member-result-address">

          </address>
      </div>
</div>
<div class="search-member-form">
     <input class="search-member-input" id="search-member-lastname" placeholder="Name">
     <input class="search-member-input" id="search-member-firstname" placeholder="Vorname">
     <div class="search-member-submit-btn">suchen</div>
</div>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    echo $lastname;
?>
```

Comment: Check the Network tab of developer tools to see the raw response from the AJAX call.

Comment: Is the `alert()` firing? What does it show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add response type like :

```
 $.ajax({//AJAX request
        type: "post",
        url: "/website/include/process/send_membersearchrequest_process.php",
        async: true,
        data: {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname},
        dataType: 'json', // You have to add this line
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.response);
            $(".search-member-result-address").html(data.response);
        },
    });
```

and your PHP file :

```
<?php 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
echo json_encode(array('response' => $lastname));
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work if his original, simpler code, didn't?

Comment: `data` should be `data.response`.

Comment: thx for support. now it alerts [object Object]. why doesn't it display the lastname-string?

Comment: alert(data.response); instead of alert(data);

Answer (score 1):

I rather do this :

Javascript

```
$.ajax({//AJAX request
        type: "POST",
        url: "/website/include/process/send_membersearchrequest_process.php",
        async: true,
        dataType:'json'
        data: {"firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.result);
            $(".search-member-result-address").html(data.result);
        },
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php 
      $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
      $res = array("result" => $lastname);
      echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

Like this, you send a json to your server and get a json in return.

Comment: While this is a good style, it doesn't explain why his original code doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing `dataType: 'json'` in the AJAX call.